# How to include a package in my package

Tags: python

I got a package from GitHub and put it in `my_package/someones_package` directory.
Now I can `import someones_package` from `my_package` directory.

However, if there are `file1.py` and `file2.py` in `someones_package` and `file2.py` imports `file1.py`, when I try to `import someones_package.file2`,  it fails because base directory is not `someones_package` but `my_package` and there is no `file1.py` in `my_package`.

How do I correctly include someone's package in my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you descriptions.I try to create the directories and files.
[image]

If you want to import file2 in file1.py

you should use `import my_package.someones_package.file2`

And if you want to import file1 in file2.py

you should use `import my_package.someones_package.file1`

If you thinks it is too long and want to make it easy to use(assume there is a function name fun in file1),we can use:

```
import my_package.someones_package.file1 as a
a.fun()
```